# Synaptic installs Firefox when uninstalling Chromium

Tags: lubuntu

I use Iron so I wanted to uninstall Chromium, so I marked the packages for removal in Synaptic and clicked "go" and I was startled to see Synaptic install Firefox. After that was done, I marked the FF packages for removal and took a closer look. Synaptic wanted to install Epiphany. What the heck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do:

```
aptitude why firefox
```

you can find what package is requiring firefox. In my case it was gecko media player, so I removed it and chromium could be removed no problem.

Answer (score 1):

There must be something depending on the www-browser virtual package ( http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/www-browser).

Comment: After installing Epiphany (on the list of www-browsers), I could uninstall Chromium without being forced to install Firefox.

Comment: This post at [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11169574&postcount=3) suggests that it is possible by unchecking the "suggested" browser before clicking "apply". I have not verified it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you dont have any other browser except Chromium which is why synaptic trying to install ffox.

Comment: I installed Iron right after installing Lubuntu. So yes, there is a browser. You think it's because Iron is not in that list?

Comment: @CuriousApprentice This should only happen if there is a package installed that requires some browser to be installed. Do you know what that might be? Do you agree with [Siegfreid Gevatter](http://askubuntu.com/users/5117/siegfried-gevatter) that [it's `www-browsser`](http://askubuntu.com/a/127833/22949)?

Comment: I installed **dillo**, a light browser from the [list linked to above](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/www-browser), but `apt-get` still wants to install Firefox. I'll try again, when I reboot and post back here. (I have Google Chrome 21 from Google's ppa and don't need Chromium 20.)

Comment: Same result after a reboot.