# What is apt-get equivalent of "aptitude why"?

Tags: apt, aptitude

In [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/197696/248158), I came across this command:

```
aptitude why firefox
```

`aptitude why`looks like an useful command but I don't want to install aptitude just for that. What is the `apt-get` equivalent of `aptitude why`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of `apt-get` I would have a look at apt-cache, though not one on one the same but close will be:

```
apt-cache --installed rdepends firefox
```

Comment: This is not right answer. There is no similar for `aptitude why`

Comment: Thanks! I mentioned apt-get but apt-cache will do just as well because it is installed by default. I should have made my question clear on this point!

Comment: Even though these two commands are not the same

Comment: @maythux, as mentioned in my answer. But it comes close and gives reverse dependencies so it is useful for most users who ask this, so why not mention it?

Comment: The command

    aptitude why firefox

gives

    i   firefox-gnome-support Depends firefox

The command

    apt-cache --installed rdepends firefox

gives:

    firefox
    Reverse Depends:
     |rhythmbox-mozilla
      firefox-gnome-support
      flashplugin-installer
      xul-ext-ubufox
      xul-ext-ubufox
      ubuntu-desktop
     |totem-mozilla
     |rhythmbox-mozilla
      flashplugin-installer
      xul-ext-ubufox
      xul-ext-ubufox
      ubuntu-desktop
     |totem-mozilla
     |rhythmbox-mozilla
      hunspell-en-us
      hunspell-en-ca
      firefox-gnome-support

Comment: Yes, the difference is in what reverse dependency was manually installed versus what reverse dependency is installed.

Comment: As suggested [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5636/can-i-see-why-a-package-is-installed#comment505140_5637) there is a bunch of other options you might want to add; `apt-cache rdepends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances --installed --recurse $package`

Answer (score 4):

> People might want to know why an automatically installed package is
>   present on the system. To get this information from the command line,
>   you can use aptitude why package
>
> **apt-get has no similar feature**

source:[debian-handbook](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/wheezy/sect.apt-get.html)

Comment: It was my mistake. I mentioned apt-get but main thing is I didn't want new software. apt-cache is there already! Sorry about confusion :)

Comment: So Why downvoting?!